# How do I talk about a particular constructor in Agda

Tags: agda

Say I have

```
data Maybe : Set -> Set where
    Just : forall {A} -> A -> Maybe A
    Nothing : forall {A} -> Maybe A
```

and I define my own minus like

```
minus : Nat -> Nat -> Maybe Nat
minus zero zero       = Just zero
minus zero _          = Nothing
minus n zero          = Just n
minus (suc n) (suc m) = minus n m
```

and I would like to prove that forall m n, if m > n, (minus m n) always spits out a (Just Nat).
I am wondering how I can encode this claim in a type.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard library's [Is-just](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Maybe.Base.html#2489). Your statement will look like:

```
lt-minus-total : ∀ n m → m < n → Is-just (minus n m)
```